# Can I install httpcfg.exe where Windows XP SP3 is already installed?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-5

Can I install `httpcfg.exe` from the [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49ae8576-9bb9-4126-9761-ba8011fabf38) if XP Service Pack 3 is already installed?

Do I require admin rights to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this question belongs here, but I would refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article for more information.

I don't see a problem "installing" this utility as it's a stand-alone application that doesn't require installation. You won't need administrator permissions depending on where you want to store this utility on your machine. Using the utility, however, will require administrator permissions.